# jhipster react application error on Internet Explorer11

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I built an application using jhipster v5.3.4 choosing React option for frontend. It works fine with Edge and Chrome but renders a blank page on Internet Explorer 11.

I've read the solution is install and include babel-polyfill but I´m not sure how to do this.

What I've done:

- npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
- At the top of index.tsx, add `import babelPolyfill from 'babel-polyfill';`

The result is the same, blank page and console error: "Symbol is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the answer to make it works is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Comment: *sigh* not getting working on version 6.1.2 - any thoughts would be appreciated!